# Prevent pop-up window from closing itself - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing e2e tests for social authentication. In Selenium, when the sign in button is clicked, the pop up window opens as expected, however it immediately closes by itself hence not allowing me write any assertions. I'm running selenium in Firefox and here's the code snippet:

```
main_handle = self.browser.current_window_handle
self.browser.find_element_by_id('in-btn-link').click()
all_handles = self.browser.window_handles

for handle in all_handles:
    if handle != main_handle:
        auth_handle = handle
        break
self.browser.switch_to.window(auth_handle)
```

Is there a way for me to take control of the popup window and prevent it from automatically closing?

Comment: Can you share page URL?

Comment: @Andersson it's still on localhost.